# How to change files with a specific word to end in.fasta

Tags: linux, find, rename, filenames, bioinformatics

How do I select and change files that have a specific word in it to all end in ".fasta"?

For example I'm selecting files with the word "car" in it.

```
find /home/user -name "*car*"
```

which gives me

```
/home/user/car.txt
/home/user/scar.fa
/home/user/cart.fa
/home/user/scart.fasta
```

but I don't how to change them so they all end in ".fasta"

So the end result would be

```
/home/user/car.fasta
/home/user/scar.fasta
/home/user/cart.fasta
/home/user/scart.fasta
```

Comment: This might be a duplicate but here is one way to do it: `find /home/user/ -type f -name '*car*' -exec bash -c 'for f; do mv "$f" "${f%.*}".fasta; done' _ {} +`

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use `rename` as command in the `-exec` option of `find`:

```
find /home/user -name "*car*" -exec rename 's/[^.]*$/fasta/' {} \;
```

The `[^.]*$` matches all non-dots at the end of the file name and replaces them with the `fasta` extension.

If you don't know the command, have a look at `man rename`.

Comment: Did you test the command?   It does not work for me.

Comment: Yes, it's tested. What does "not work" mean? Error message? Nothing happens? Wrong thing happens?

Comment: Does not work on Fedora 26.   Says `rename: not enough arguments`   Are you using Ubuntu?

Comment: I'm using Debian Stretch with `bash`. Maybe it gives a hint when you place `echo` before `rename` so we see what happens to the two obvious arguments.

Comment: I seem to recall that OOTB the Debian version of `rename` is different than the Redhat/CentOS/Fedora version of `rename`

Answer (score 0):

For a bash solution, see this overview of [substring removal](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#substring_removal).

```
#!/bin/bash

for f in *car*; do
   [[ ${f##*.} == "fasta" ]] && continue

   f_no_ext="${f%%.*}"

   if [[ -e "${f_no_ext}.fasta" ]]; then
      echo "Not moving $f because it would clobber ${f_no_ext}.fasta"
      continue
   fi

   mv "$f" "${f_no_ext}.fasta"
done

exit
```

This loops over all `*car*` files and renames them to a .fasta extension, skipping those that already end in .fasta.  I think other solutions might be overlooking that step.

EDIT: I added the `if` block to check if the file with .fasta extension already exists to avoid overwriting files.  For example, if you have car.txt and car.fasta.

Answer (score 0):

Another way using a loop and the `mv` command:

```
find /home/user -type f -name "*car*" | while read f; do mv -v "$f" "${f%.*}.fasta"; done
```